If $3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)-4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)+2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\fracπ3$, then find $x$
The following question is taken from JEE practice set.

If $3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)-4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)+2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\fracπ3$, where $|x|<1$, then find $x$

Case$1:$
$0≤x<1\implies0≤\tan^{-1}x<\fracπ4\implies0≤\theta<\fracπ4\implies0≤2\theta<\fracπ2$
The given equation can be written as
$3\sin^{-1}\sin2\theta-4\cos^{-1}\cos2\theta+2\tan^{-1}\tan2\theta=\fracπ3$
$\implies6\theta-8\theta+4\theta=\fracπ3\implies2\theta=\fracπ3\implies x=\frac1{√3}$
Case$2:$
$-1<x<0\implies-\fracπ4<\tan^{-1}x<0\implies-\fracπ4≤\theta<0\implies-\fracπ2≤2\theta<0$
The given equation can be written as
$3\sin^{-1}\sin2\theta-4\cos^{-1}\cos(-2\theta)+2\tan^{-1}\tan2\theta=\fracπ3$
$\implies6\theta+8\theta+4\theta=\fracπ3\implies\theta=\fracπ{54}$
But on wolfram, there appears to be only one solution.
Seems like I made a mistake in case$2$. Can you point out? Thanks.

The second case has its restriction that -1<x<0 which implies $-\pi/4<\arctan x<0$.
($\theta=arctan x$). Thus $\theta=\pi/54$ is an extraneous solution that does not satisfy the given restriction and should therefore be excluded from the solution set.

@dev, thanks, please post this as an answer, so that I could accept it, thanks

@aarbee hello...if you don't mind, how old r u?? are you preparing for jee or just solving these questions for fun?

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous solving for fun. Just checked your profile. Seems like you just appeared in jee in the recent past

@aarbee that's nice, comrade...and yeah i gave it last year

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous this website is gonna help you in your graduation as well. See you around

@aarbee , wishing you a good luck

The equation is:
$$3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)-4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)+2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}3$$
Let $x=\tan t$:
$$3\sin^{-1}(\sin2t)-4\cos^{-1}(\cos2t)+2\tan^{-1}(\tan2t)=\dfrac{\pi}3$$
We are given that $|x|<1$ which implies $2t\in(-\dfrac{\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2)$.
Note that for $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, we have $\sin^{-1}(\sin(\theta))=\tan^{-1}(\tan(\theta))=\theta$.
However, $\cos^{-1}(\cos\theta)=  \begin{cases} {-\theta} & {\theta\in(-\dfrac{\pi}2,0]} \\ {\theta} & {\theta\in[0,\dfrac{\pi}2)} \end{cases}  $. Hence, we should consider two cases:
Case 1:$\quad2t\in(-\dfrac{\pi}2, 0]$:
$$6t\color{red}+8t+4t=\dfrac{\pi}3\Rightarrow t=\dfrac{\pi}{54}$$
Which is a contradiction.
Case 2: $\quad2t\in[0,\dfrac{\pi}2)$:
$$6t\color{red}-8t+4t=\dfrac{\pi}3\Rightarrow t=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$
Hence, $x=\tan(\pi/6)=\dfrac{\sqrt3}3$.

If $2t\in(-\fracπ2,\fracπ2)$ then $\cos^{-1}\cos2t$ is not equal to $2t$, right? For that to happen, domain should be in $0$ to $π$ right? For $-π/2$ to $0$, wouldn't we get $-2t$ instead? (Hence my two cases)

You are right, I'm editing my answer.
